# Hibernate error:- Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have a maven web project which uses hibernate and JPA. The following error is occurring at the time of execution of APIs

```
org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure : 39
 HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0];
 actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
```

The system executes multiple APIs at a time but not able to determine the use case for this error.
I tried executing multiple APIs separately to replicate the error but this error is not occurring. Even the stack trace is not getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception while deleting a record by Id that does not exists at all. So check that record you are updating/Deleting actually exists in DB

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code snippet and also check your transaction boundaries.